# Generate a color range selection from an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, polygon, graphicspath

I have an image and I would like to create a `GraphicsPath` representing a selection on the image based on some sort of thresholding on the pixels making up the image. For instance a color range algorithm that takes into account pixels with color values close to a given color.

My problem at the moment is not on the algorithm to select pixels, but on the `GraphicsPath` which with my current code becomes far too complicated (too many points) and hence time-expensive to create it and especially to further manage it.

At the moment I'm simply using the following code (in this example I simply take opaque pixels) where I add a `Rectangle` for each taken pixel.

```
BitmapData bitmapData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);

GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

unsafe
{
    byte* imagePointer = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++)
    {
         for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++)
         {
              if (imagePointer[3] != 0)
                  gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
              imagePointer += 4;
          }
     }
 }
```

How can I simplify this process or the resulting `GraphicsPath` to obtain a much simpler path, ideally with only contours?

**EDIT**
I will then use to path to: display its contours on screen (running ants); use it as a mask for other images (cancel what is out from the path); do hit tests (whether a point is inside the path). As an example:
[image]

Comment: Adding single pixels to a path indeed will not be efficient, infact it sounds rather crazy.. What exactly do you want to achieve with the path? Can you post an example image? You can use a Floodfill algorithm to find connected areas of same or similar pixels..

Comment: I've added some uses I intend to do on the path. Could you please provide some more details on how to proceed with a floodfill? Once I have all the pixels I want to take, how do I generate the GraphicsPath?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with the path? Can you post an example image?

Comment: I added a quick example of a selection by color range on a image. I would like to get that GraphicsPath comprising for instance all the orange colors

Comment: This is a really tough task and unless the images are very helpful you can't hope for any simple solution. If you take the example image you could easily __trace__ the selection by following pixels of the same hue, which would be the general approach but the general case will be rather difficult. I would try to find a free library that can help.